# Jetty MultiPartFilter throws SocketTimeoutException while uploading large file

Tags: java, timeout, jetty, multipart

I have some problems when uploading large files to an embedded jetty server from an unreliable network connection (3G). It looks like often, at a random point, the MultiPartFilter will throw a SocketTimeoutException when trying to read the request's InputStream.

Is there a way to increase the timeout parameter to reduce the number of failure?
If yes, is it possible to increase it only for this specific servlet action?

Answer (score 0):

Set the timeout on the connector.  See the section below on maxIdleTime

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Connectors

I do not believe you can configure this to the the granularity your looking for, short of using multiple connectors and structuring your handlers and filters accordingly.